# Series exapnsion of the sum of the $3n^3$-th powers of the first n positive integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $S_{n,m}$ be the sum of the m-th powers of the first n positive integers:
$$S_{n,m}=\sum_{k=1}^n k^m=\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k+1)^m\tag{1}$$

If $m\in\mathbb{N}$, and $m<<n$, we can use the Bernoulli formula to express $S_{n,m}$ as a order $(n+1)$ polynomials of $n$:

$$S_{n,m}=\frac{1}{m+1}\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{m+1}{j}B_j n^{m+1-j}\tag{2}$$
where $B_j$ (with convention $B_1=1/2$) are the Bernolli numbers.

Let $m(n)=3 n^3+a_2 n^2+a_1 n+a_0$;$a_k\in\mathbb{N},k=0,1,2$. We are looking for series expansion near $n=\infty$ of $h(n)$:

$$h(n):=\frac{S_{n,m(n)+2}}{n^2S_{n,m(n)}}=1+\cdots\tag{3}$$

***Question***
What are the second and third term in the right hand side of (3)? How to do this kind of expansion in general?

thanks-
mike